# Custom label for dataPoints in scatter chart

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I am using EPPlus to generate an Excel using C#.

**My Requirement**

I need to give a custom label for the dataPoints plotted in my scatter chart.
By default - on hover of a datapoint on the chart it shows only the X-Axis and Y-Axis Value.

Along with X\Y Axis I would need include a data  *TimeReceived* that I have on the Excel columns

Excel columns : `X Value, Y Value , TimeReceived`

*My Current Code*

```
var scatterChart = 
    workSheet.Drawings.AddChart("scatterChart", eChartType.XYScatterLines) as ExcelScatterChart;

scatterChart.Title.Text = GraphTitle;
var rangeLabel = workSheet.Cells["D2:D2571"];
var range1 = workSheet.Cells["C2:C2571"];

scatterChart.Series.Add(range1, rangeLabel);

scatterChart.Series[0].Header = workSheet.Cells["A1"].Value.ToString();
scatterChart.Legend.Position = eLegendPosition.Right;
scatterChart.SetSize(600, 300);

scatterChart.SetPosition(5, 0, 1, 0);
```

Please share your suggestions on this.

Answer (score 1):

EPPlus does not support that itself, but it is possible to add Open Office XML to do it.

```
   private static void addScatterChartToEntityMetricSheet(ExcelWorksheet sheet, ExcelTable table, string labelColumnName, string graphName)
    {
        int columnIndexART = table.Columns["ART"].Position;
        ExcelRangeBase rangeART = table.WorkSheet.Cells[
            table.Address.Start.Row + 1,
            table.Address.Start.Column + columnIndexART,
            table.Address.End.Row,
            table.Address.Start.Column + columnIndexART];

        int columnIndexCPM = table.Columns["CPM"].Position;
        ExcelRangeBase rangeCPM = table.WorkSheet.Cells[
            table.Address.Start.Row + 1,
            table.Address.Start.Column + columnIndexCPM,
            table.Address.End.Row,
            table.Address.Start.Column + columnIndexCPM];

        int columnIndexLabels = table.Columns[labelColumnName].Position;
        ExcelRangeBase rangeLabels = table.WorkSheet.Cells[
            table.Address.Start.Row + 1,
            table.Address.Start.Column + columnIndexLabels,
            table.Address.End.Row,
            table.Address.Start.Column + columnIndexLabels];

        //Scatter plot of activities
        ExcelChart chart = sheet.Drawings.AddChart(graphName, eChartType.XYScatter);
        ExcelScatterChart chart1 = (ExcelScatterChart)chart;
        chart.SetPosition(0, 0, 2, 0);
        chart.SetSize(800, 300);
        chart.Legend.Remove();
        chart.XAxis.Title.Text = "ART";
        chart.XAxis.Title.Font.Size = 8;
        chart.YAxis.Title.Text = "CPM";
        chart.YAxis.Title.Font.Size = 8;
        chart.VaryColors = true;
        //chart1.BubbleScale = 50;

        ExcelChartSerie series = chart.Series.Add(rangeCPM, rangeART);
        ExcelScatterChartSerie series1 = (ExcelScatterChartSerie)series;
        series.Header = "ARTvsCPM";
        series1.DataLabel.ShowValue = true;
        series1.DataLabel.ShowCategory = true;
        series1.DataLabel.ShowValue = false;
        series1.DataLabel.ShowCategory = false;
        series1.DataLabel.Position = eLabelPosition.Top;
        series1.MarkerSize = 10;
        series1.Marker = eMarkerStyle.Diamond;

        #region Update scatter to include nice Tier labels

        // This is what the Chart looks looks like
        //<ser xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/chart">
        //    <c:idx val="0" />
        //    <c:order val="0" />
        //    <c:tx>
        //        <c:v>ARTvsCPM</c:v>
        //    </c:tx>
        //    <c:dLbls>
        //        <c:dLblPos val="ctr" />
        //        <c:showLegendKey val="0" />
        //        <c:showVal val="1" />
        //        <c:showCatName val="1" />
        //        <c:showSerName val="0" />
        //        <c:showPercent val="0" />
        //        <c:showBubbleSize val="0" />
        //        <c:separator>
        //        </c:separator>
        //        <c:showLeaderLines val="0" />
        //        <c:extLst>   
        //            <c:ext uri="{CE6537A1-D6FC-4f65-9D91-7224C49458BB}" xmlns:c15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2012/chart">  <<< Magic GUID!!!!! Ai caramba
        //                <c15:showDataLabelsRange val="1"/>   <<<< This is the thing that turns on the data labels range
        //                <c15:showLeaderLines val="0"/>
        //            </c:ext>
        //        </c:extLst>
        //    </c:dLbls>
        //    <c:spPr>
        //        <a:ln w="28575">
        //            <a:noFill />
        //        </a:ln>
        //    </c:spPr>
        //    <c:xVal>
        //        <c:numRef>
        //            <c:f>'5.Tiers.Hourly'!$F$19:$F$40</c:f>
        //        </c:numRef>
        //    </c:xVal>
        //    <c:yVal>
        //        <c:numRef>
        //            <c:f>'5.Tiers.Hourly'!$I$19:$I$40</c:f>
        //        </c:numRef>
        //    </c:yVal>
        //    <c:smooth val="0" />
        //    <c:extLst>
        //        <c:ext uri="{02D57815-91ED-43cb-92C2-25804820EDAC}" xmlns:c15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2012/chart">   <<< Magic GUID!!!!! Ai caramba
        //            <c15:datalabelsRange>
        //                <c15:f>'5.Tiers.Hourly'!$C$19:$C$40</c15:f>  <<<<< This is what specifies the range
        //            </c15:datalabelsRange>
        //        </c:ext>
        //    </c:extLst>
        //</ser>

        XmlDocument chartXMLdoc = chart.ChartXml;
        XmlNamespaceManager manager = new XmlNamespaceManager(chartXMLdoc.NameTable);
        manager.AddNamespace("c", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/chart");
        manager.AddNamespace("c15", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2012/chart");

        XmlNode seriesXmlNode = chartXMLdoc.GetElementsByTagName("ser")[0];

        // Turn on labels
        // /ser/c:dLbls/c:extLst/c:ext/c15:showDataLabelsRange
        XmlNode labelXmlNode = seriesXmlNode.SelectSingleNode("c:dLbls", manager);
        XmlNode extLstXmlNode = chartXMLdoc.CreateElement("c:extLst", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/chart");
        labelXmlNode.AppendChild(extLstXmlNode);
        XmlNode extXmlNode = chartXMLdoc.CreateElement("c:ext", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/chart");
        XmlAttribute attribXmlAttribute = chartXMLdoc.CreateAttribute("uri");
        attribXmlAttribute.Value = "{CE6537A1-D6FC-4f65-9D91-7224C49458BB}";
        extXmlNode.Attributes.Append(attribXmlAttribute);
        extLstXmlNode.AppendChild(extXmlNode);
        XmlNode showDataLabelsRangeXmlNode = chartXMLdoc.CreateElement("showDataLabelsRange", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2012/chart");
        attribXmlAttribute = chartXMLdoc.CreateAttribute("val");
        attribXmlAttribute.Value = "1";
        showDataLabelsRangeXmlNode.Attributes.Append(attribXmlAttribute);
        extXmlNode.AppendChild(showDataLabelsRangeXmlNode);

        // Specify label range
        // /ser/c:extLst/c:ext/c15:datalabelsRange/c15:f
        extLstXmlNode = chartXMLdoc.CreateElement("c:extLst", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/chart");
        seriesXmlNode.AppendChild(extLstXmlNode);
        extXmlNode = chartXMLdoc.CreateElement("c:ext", "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/chart");
        attribXmlAttribute = chartXMLdoc.CreateAttribute("uri");
        attribXmlAttribute.Value = "{02D57815-91ED-43cb-92C2-25804820EDAC}";
        extXmlNode.Attributes.Append(attribXmlAttribute);
        extLstXmlNode.AppendChild(extXmlNode);
        XmlNode datalabelsRangeXmlNode = chartXMLdoc.CreateElement("datalabelsRange", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2012/chart");
        extXmlNode.AppendChild(datalabelsRangeXmlNode);
        XmlNode fXmlNode = chartXMLdoc.CreateElement("f", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/drawing/2012/chart");
        fXmlNode.InnerText = rangeLabels.FullAddress;
        datalabelsRangeXmlNode.AppendChild(fXmlNode);

        #endregion
    }
```

It produces image shown here https://github.com/Appdynamics/AppDynamics.DEXTER/wiki/Entity-Metrics-Report#5tiers

Comment: I was able to use this answer as inspiration for adding alternative labels for my clustered bar chart. Appreciate it!